# Sequential training data for XOR Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am trying to implement a recurrent neural network and trying to get it to learn an XOR function as a petty example.

As it is a recurrent network, I thought it could be good to have it work with just one input unit in order to see how well it does remembering its previous state; that is, implementing the XOR function based on a sequential input:

```
INPUT(t-1) = 0
INPUT(t)   = 1
OUTPUT(t)  = 1
```

or

```
INPUT(t-1) = 1
INPUT(t)   = 1
OUTPUT(t)  = 0
```

So my input training data be presented one bit at a time in this order:

```
inputs = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 }
```

and the corresponding target output

```
targets = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 }.
```

But it is not learning and, even though I know there can be many reasons for that, I was wondering that maybe I did not define properly my dataset and thus I wouldn't be presenting the right problem to my network. I come here then looking for ideas on what could be a right training set for a supervised learning of a "sequential" XOR function.

The implementation I am working on is similar to the Elman RNN, if you need any details on it, please ask.

Comment: Are you following forward propagation - back propagation well? I would suggest to refer Andrew Ng lec (https://class.coursera.org/ml/auth/welcome?type=logout&visiting=https%3A%2F%2Fclass.coursera.org%2Fml%2Flecture%2Findex) and Chap 4 from Mitchell's book ... I implemented neural network code .. I used it for Encoding-decoding and I used "same" for Handwritten digit recognition too.

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using BTT (backprop through time)?

Answer (score 0):

The following link: https://code.google.com/p/encog-java/source/browse/trunk/encog-examples/src/org/encog/examples/neural/recurrent/elman/ElmanXOR.java?r=2423

contains a recurrent Elman network implementation that works with the XOR problem.  It uses Encog (which is relatively easy to use) to handle the implementation of the network itself.  Hopefully you will be able to see the difference in your implementation and correct.